# LINQ Join gives only first result multiple times

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Join :

```
var mycust= db.CUSTOMER.Where(x => x.NAME.Contains(nameid)).ToList();

var CancCustomer = (from cust in myCust
                    join ip in db.IPS on must.ID equals ip.CUSTOMER_ID                              
                    select new JoinObj {ID = cust.ID, NAME = cust.NAME, LASTNAME = cust.LASTNAME, 
                                        TYPE_ID = ip.TYPE_ID, TYPE2_ID = ip.TYPE2_ID,
                                        SERVICE_ID = ip.SERVICE_ID , REASON = ip.REASON }).ToList();
```

This code returns the first linq result multiple times? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: are `cust.ID` different in selected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Where`, you should use `SingleOrDefault`/`Single` - these would indeed return a single row into your `mycust` variable.

`SingleOrDefault` would put a `null` into the variable if no such customers were found (and assuming a `Customer` is a reference type - if it were a value type, it would be the default value for the type). `Single` would throw an exception if no items were found or more than one were found, which could be very useful in finding errors in your data (such as duplicate customer records).

Additionally, it is likely your `ip` table has multiple matching records for a customer - which is why you would be seeing multiple records being returned from your `select`.

Comment: But I don't want single result. I want all results from that join.

Comment: This will return the all the results from that join - I am just saying you want to rule out getting multiple customer records. You are also picking out specific information from the ip table - did you check in your database that these bits are indeed different for your customer? Could be that nothing is wrong - that the data is indeed identical (for the bits in your `select`).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple Duplicate Record received Then Try For following quires

```
var mycust= db.CUSTOMER.Where(x => x.NAME.Contains(nameid)).ToList();

var CancCustomer = (from cust in myCust
                    join ip in db.IPS on cust.ID equals ip.CUSTOMER_ID                              
                    select new JoinObj {ID = cust.ID, NAME = cust.NAME, ASTNAME=cust.LASTNAME, TYPE_ID = ip.TYPE_ID, TYPE2_ID = ip.TYPE2_ID, SERVICE_ID = ip.SERVICE_ID , REASON = ip.REASON }).distinct().ToList();
```

Other Wise Multiple record then You Get One Record for You following Query

```
  

var mycust= db.CUSTOMER.Where(x => x.NAME.Contains(nameid)).ToList();

var CancCustomer = (from cust in myCust
                    join ip in db.IPS on must.ID equals ip.CUSTOMER_ID                              
                    select new JoinObj {ID = cust.ID, NAME = cust.NAME, LASTNAME = cust.LASTNAME, TYPE_ID = ip.TYPE_ID, TYPE2_ID = ip.TYPE2_ID, SERVICE_ID = ip.SERVICE_ID , REASON = ip.REASON }).distinct().FirstOrDefault();
```